# MarkLogic - How to improve application Logging

Tags: logging, marklogic

MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

At present we are using following way to Log/view debug/information/warning/errors in  MarkLogic log files

- XDMP:Log in Xquery with log level including within try-catch block
- Application level logs

What are the best practices we should follow for logging and maintaining the same code in dev/ST/UAT/Prod environment.

Answer (score 5):

xdmp:log statements can be useful, but can also end up cluttering the logs making troubleshooting more difficult.  Instead of just putting in xdmp:log statements in your code you might want to use [xdmp:trace](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:trace) with specific traces which you can enable or disable at will.

This should allow the same code to be deployed to different environments, and support debugging and troubleshooting when needed, without overwhelming the logs.

Comment: Thanks Michael for quick reply. I looked at for examples, can you please share few examples on how implement it in code and how to manage with different environment without code changes?

Comment: @Micheal, Can you please help me to find some real time example with how to deploy in different environments ?

Comment: @ManishJoisar - I will look into getting some examples, but it will likely be next week.

Comment: @Micheal, If you get time, can you please share details